# Отправка формы

Tags: html

Можно ли отправлять данные формы сразу на несколько ресурсов? Например, при нажатии на кнопку `<input type="submit"...>` данные формы отправлялись, к примеру, на ресурсы "file1.php", "file2.php" и "file3.php". Если да, то подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом.

Comment: Говорят на ресурсы, а не на файлы.

Comment: Ок. Исправлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

submit'ом нельзя, это синхронный запрос он ждёт ответа.
Если бы так было сделать можно, то от кого ответа бы он ждал?

Если вам нужно отправить данные в три места, а ответ обрабатывать в js, то воспользуйтесь ajax'ом.

Comment: А через ajax я могу отправить заполненное текстовое поле (к примеру, в нём записано число 4) в три файла? Возможно ли это сделать отправляя в файлы, имена которых "file1.HTML", "file2.HTML, "file3.HTML" (т.е. в файл формата HTML а не PHP)?

Comment: Отправить Ajax'ом можно на 3 URL разные, это не проблема.

Но если там статика (т.е. голый HTML, который никак сервером не обрабатывается) лежит, то что вы будете делать с параметрами, которые передаёте?

Comment: Не знаю. На моей форме нужно передать значение одного текстового поля на три файла. Вот у меня ещё и проблема в том, что сайт весь построен на HTML. Так что пока думаю, что делать дальше...

Answer (score 1):

Можно отправлять на один обработчик, а с него [curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)'ом рассылать на нужные.