# Отправка формы одновременно по нескольким адресам

Tags: html

Будет ли в данном случае текст `text` отправляться сразу на два файла?

```
<form method="post" action="file1.htm">
    <form method="post" action="file2.htm">
        <input type="text" id="text" value="12345">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</form>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправка формы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395492/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: Нет. В том вопросе я спрашивал про возможные варианты, можно ли так вообще такое сделать. А здесь я попробовал так сделать, и спросил, можно ли так сделать. И вообще, честно говоря, я уже не помню, пол года прошло..

Comment: Можно сделать [так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535804/201026).

Comment: Совершенно верно. Но всё же, мой вопрос нельзя назвать дубликатом, как сказал @Arhad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя, потому что форма `method="post"`, и происходит переход на ссылку, указанной в `action=""`. А при переходе, все функции, заданные после кода `document.getElementById("form").submit()`, не прочитываются. Данная операция была бы возможна в `method="get"`, потому что переход на другую страницу не происходит, и все коды прочитываются.

Comment: @Никита___, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Теперь подробный ответ на мой вопрос, можно сказать, есть тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535804/201026