# Как в форме можно сделать 2 action

Tags: html

```
<form action="myurl">
  <button name="test1">test1</button>
  <button name="test2">test2</button>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопки получу такие урлы:

```
myurl?test1
myurl?test2
```

Как получить урлы такого типа без js

```
myurl/test1
myurl/test2
```

Comment: Вы хотите изменить стандартное поведение форм средствами чистого HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Основываясь на ответе @Geslot, вы также можете использовать атрибут [`formaction`](https://webref.ru/html/button/formaction):

```
<form>

    <button formaction="myurl/test1">test1</button>

    <button formaction="myurl/test2">test2</button>

</form>
```

---

Пример с полем:

```
<form target="_blank">

    <input type="text" name="q" value="Hello, World!">

    <button formaction="//bing.com/search">Bing Search</button>

    <button formaction="//google.com/search">Google Search</button>

</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f5po9zck/

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="myurl/test1">
  <button>test1</button>
</form>
<form action="myurl/test2>
  <button>test2</button>
</form>
```